# How to use Photoshop Portable in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, adobe-photoshop, wine

Im having a hard time installing or using Photoshop Portable in ubuntu, I have come to into different forums in order to find a way to use PS in ubuntu.

I already downloaded wine, that's how far i have gone.

can anybody help me with these?

thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

First off, there is no Photoshop Portable or Photoshop Lite version published or supported by Adobe. If you find a Photoshop Portable version available for download it is an illegal cracked version of Photoshop at best, or malware and virus-ridden at worst.  The latter is probably why its not working under Ubuntu.

In addition to that, according to [WineHQ](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=17) Photoshop is not fully supported under Wine.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about wine but have you considered using VirtualBox and installing micro XP or the likes to run adobe software. This would make things very easy for you.

Virtual Machines are recommended as the software is very unlikely to throw any irregular problems.

Comment: i don't know about VirtualBox and microXP man,can you help me? thanks

Comment: The idea of VirtualBox is that it creates a file on your computer that is used as a hard drive for another operating system. It operates within Linux and boots up within a window. If requires you have a bootable disk for windows made. I advise you try and get the software downloaded and installed then when you have any difficulties I can give you guidance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your terminal
2. Type in terminal
   HTML Code:
   winecfg
   ( a window should pop up)
3. Down you should see a Operating System name (mine is Windows XP)
4. Press on it and then scroll up until you see Windows 7
5. Press on "Windows 7"
6. After you pressed it, you need to press "OK"
7. Open PhotoShop Portable, and it should work